# Extend PHP functions in an external file

Tags: php, yii, orm, crm, extend

I'm developing on an open source CRM platform call Zurmo. It uses Yii Framework along with RedBean. Im trying to "extend?" or make changes to a function within a particular "module". I want to know if it is possible to create a separate file in which I would be able to change any variables or arrays within the original function.

I am still having trouble defining classes and class functions in an external file. I created a file within accounts/models/ called AccountExtend.php and loaded it thought the AccountsModule.php on line 53 like this:

```
public function getRootModelNames()
    {
        return array('Account, AccountExtend');
    }
```

Within the AccountExtend.php file I have this function which is changing the label from the default "Billing Address" to say "Property Address"

```
class AccountExtend extends Account implements StarredInterface
{
     protected static function translatedAttributeLabels($language)
    {
        $params = LabelUtil::getTranslationParamsForAllModules();
        $paramsForAffiliations = $params;

        return array_merge(OwnedSecurableItem::translatedAttributeLabels($language),
            array(

                'billingAddress'         => Zurmo::t('AccountsModule',      'Property Address',                     array(), null, $language),

            )
        );

    }
```

So above I merge this array with the class "OwnedSecurableItem" formerly being merged in the extended Account.php and replaced "OwnedSecurableItem" with "AccountExtend" within the Account.php model and did a "merge_diff" php function to overwrite the default label.

Now my question is this, Is this the best way to do this? any tips or advice? My next struggle is trying to extend a function within the Account.php module to say add a custom relational drop down field or to add any other functionality. How can I go about this since these are more complex arrays that contain elements?

Comment: i thought i had deleted that post. sorry. thanks for catching that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a method is public or protected it can be overwritten in the new class, for example:

```
class Your_New_Class extends Account
{    

    protected static function translatedAttributeLabels($language)
    {

        //Your new logic

    }

}
```

Comment: and this "new logic" will be changed on the Accounts module too? I thought the logic was just overwritten for the New Class?

Comment: Without editing the actual Account class, you can't change the logic of that method (except extending in a new class).

The "old" functionality would remain in the Account class, and the new functionality would live in the new class. You could then do:

Account::translatedAttributeLabels() to access the old logic, and Your_New_Class::translatedAttributeLabels() to access the new logic if desired.

Comment: Okay last question within a question. The main reason I'm trying to do this is to maintain the code when the CRM has updates. Is there anyway the is good practice to do this other than changing the original files after each update?

Comment: Extending it is the best way, then when the files are updated you can just move across any new logic to your new class. Otherwise editing the files direct will override any of your changes.

Comment: where/how would i include the extended file? with include?

Comment: Add the extended class in the search path (see your config/main.php how to do this) and create an instance of your extended class. In this case $account = new Your_New_Class() instead of $account = new Account();

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "the search path". I checked that file and see no files being loaded or classes being defined

Comment: @crafter I updated my question to show more code. I'm attempting to add a metadata field and cannot get it to show

Comment: @GO3DExpansion, Look for the 'import' key in config/main.php